Node-Red node-red-contrib-grpc Output differing from Straight @grpc/grpc-js and @grpc/proto-loader
I've got a strange issue, and I'm hoping I'm just missing something easy about the implementation of gRPC. I have a gRPC server that is just endlessly streaming a simple message. I'm able to connect to the server in Node-Red two different ways:

using the node-red-contrib-grpc using the grpc-call node
using a function node where I load @grpc/grpc-js and @grpc/proto-loader Node packages (these are the same packages that node-red-contrib-grpc uses).

Everything connects, and returns as expected. The only difference between the two is that one returns with the enums correctly cast as String whereas, the function node continues to leave them as Integers.
Other than this, the output is identical. I've verified that the .proto file is identical, as well.
The options that node-red-contrib-grpc uses in its server configuration uses the following options for proto-loader:
let proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(
                protoLoader.loadSync(fileName, {
                    keepCase: true,
                    longs: String,
                    enums: String,
                    defaults: true,
                    oneofs: true
                })
            );

My full function is:
const PROTO_PATH = '/data/userfiles/combined.proto';
const credentials = grpc.credentials.createInsecure();

let numberOfMessages = 1 // 0 to let the server close the stream (infinite messages)

let proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(
    protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true
    })
);
// node.warn(proto)

let metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
if (typeof msg.metadata === 'object'){
    Object.keys(msg.metadata).forEach(key => {
        try {
            metadata.add(key, JSON.stringify(msg.metadata[key]));
        } catch (e){
            node.error(e);
        }
    });
}

let client = new proto.plan.v2.PlanService('localhost:8002',
    credentials);

let dataReceived = 0
if (proto.plan.v2.PlanService.service['Subscribe'].responseStream) {
    let call = client.Subscribe({}, metadata);
    call.on("data", function (data) {
        msg.payload = data;
        node.send(msg);
        dataReceived += 1
        if (numberOfMessages > 0 && dataReceived === numberOfMessages) {
            call.cancel();
            node.done();
        }
    });

    call.on('status', function (status) {
        msg.grpc_msg = JSON.stringify(status)
        node.send(msg);
    });

    call.on('end', function () {
        msg.grpc_msg = "client connection ended";
        node.send(msg);
    });

    call.on("error",function (error) {
        msg.error = error;
        node.send(msg);
    });

} else {
    client.Subscribe({}, metadata, function(error, data) {
        msg.payload = data;
        msg.error = error;
        node.send(msg);
        node.done();
    })
}


The output only differs like so:
Output from node-red-contrib-grpc
...
{
 links: [
    { 
     link_id: "",
     type: "LINK_GROUPED_TO",
     to_id: "4dc1ab6c-5a9d-4221-83a7-986144c1cc27"
    }
  ]
}
...

Output from Function Node
...
{
 links: [
    { 
     link_id: "",
     type: 5,
     to_id: "4dc1ab6c-5a9d-4221-83a7-986144c1cc27"
    }
  ]
}
...


There isn't a question here. But if the node is doing what you expect, why are you trying to do it the "hard way" in a function especially if it give the "wrong" answer.

Just trying to understand "why." Not knowing why something is broken make the thing that works feel like relying on fairy dust to get the job done.

I'm beginning to think it is related to Node-Red itself. I've experienced a couple of edge cases specifically dealing with externally-loaded NPM modules, and seeing their base functions failing within function nodes.

Can you clarify which output corresponds to each tool?

Added a line above the output to clarify. The topmost output comes from node-red-contrib-grpc, whereas the Function Node with the external Module @grpc/grpc-js outputs the integer.

I can repro your experience. Were you able to resolve?

Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve. I have experienced a few issues that are perplexing about using External Modules in Function Nodes, but I lack the time to really dive into them. I think this it has to do with the way NR is importing modules referenced by the modules being imported (like two levels deep). I had something similar occur while using Turf.js, where no matter what I did, the function isObject() returned false, but worked perfectly when I copy/pasted the function into the  Function Node itself.

If you've time, it may  be worth reporting the(se) issue(s) on the Node-RED repo? Perhaps others are struggling with this too and it would benefit from being recognized.
